# Value turned into minus one when clicking the button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i'm making a button.
when you click the button
ScoreGame.skortotal will be deducted by totalHargaDarah
and ScoreGame.skortotal cannot deducted by totalHargaDarah when ScoreGame.skortotal >= totalHargaDarah

Here's the problem.
When Level Darah = 2, ScoreGame.skortotal = 1 and  totalHargaDarah = 2.
if (ScoreGame.skortotal >= totalHargaDarah) is not working and ScoreGame.skortotal changed to minus one when you click the button.

But when i restart the game if (ScoreGame.skortotal >= totalHargaDarah) is working and ScoreGame.skortotal not deducted by totalHargaDarah because ScoreGame.skortotal is 1 and totalHargaDarah = 2.

Here's my script

```
 public void Start()
    {    LevelDarah = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(darah, LevelDarah);
        totalHargaDarah = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HargaDarah", totalHargaDarah);

   public void Health()
    {
        if (ScoreGame.skortotal >= totalHargaDarah && LevelDarah == 1)
        {
            LevelDarah = 2;
            totalHargaDarah = 1;
            totalHargaJadi = 2;
            hargadarah.text = totalHargaJadi.ToString() + "$";
            leveldarah.text = "Level " + LevelDarah.ToString();
            ScoreGame.skortotal -= totalHargaDarah;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(ScoreGame.skorsekarang, ScoreGame.skortotal);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(darah, LevelDarah);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HargaDarah", totalHargaDarah);
            PisauScript.nyawa = 1;
        }
        else if (ScoreGame.skortotal >= totalHargaDarah && LevelDarah == 2)
        {
            LevelDarah = 3;
            totalHargaDarah = 2;
            totalHargaJadi = 3;
            hargadarah.text = totalHargaJadi.ToString() + "$";
            leveldarah.text = "Level " + LevelDarah.ToString();
            ScoreGame.skortotal -= totalHargaDarah;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(ScoreGame.skorsekarang, ScoreGame.skortotal);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(darah, LevelDarah);
            PisauScript.nyawa = 2;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HargaDarah", totalHargaDarah);
        }  }
```

Comment: Skortotal is 1. totalHargaDarah Is 2. You tell skortotal to take totalHargaDarah from itself 1-2=-1 seems it’s doing as expected

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing this

```
 if (ScoreGame.skortotal >= totalHargaDarah && LevelDarah == 1)
        {
            LevelDarah = 2;
            totalHargaDarah = 1;
            totalHargaJadi = 2;
            hargadarah.text = totalHargaJadi.ToString() + "$";
            leveldarah.text = "Level " + LevelDarah.ToString();
            ScoreGame.skortotal -= totalHargaDarah;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(ScoreGame.skorsekarang, ScoreGame.skortotal);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(darah, LevelDarah);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HargaDarah", totalHargaDarah);
            PisauScript.nyawa = 1;
        }
```

into this

```
if (ScoreGame.skortotal >= totalHargaDarah && LevelDarah == 1)
    {
        LevelDarah = 2;
        totalHargaDarah = 1;
        totalHargaJadi = 2;
        hargadarah.text = totalHargaJadi.ToString() + "$";
        leveldarah.text = "Level " + LevelDarah.ToString();
        ScoreGame.skortotal -= totalHargaDarah;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(ScoreGame.skorsekarang, ScoreGame.skortotal);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(darah, LevelDarah);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HargaDarah", totalHargaDarah);
        PisauScript.nyawa = 1;
        if(totalHargaDarah == 1)
        {
            totalHargaDarah = 2;
        }
    }
```